# Pass additional data in connection for use by PGSQL Trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I would like to add some auditing triggers to PG, to log all changes to tables.  I have found an example trigger ( [wiki.postgresql.com - 9.1+ audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) ), which gets me started.

What I would like to do is pass along some additional data automatically, such as the `user-id` or other key, so that the trigger can link the change back to the application user that made it. The basic flow would go like this:

- Get a connection for the current request
- Run custom SQL to set a context variable (`set conn_context = {userid};`)
- Read / parse that variable inside the trigger
- Write the value to a log table along with the other information

When using MS SQL I was able to execute a statement that set the context for the connection by executing `SET CONTEXT_INFO ...data...`.  I am hoping there is a way to do this for PG; I haven't found one yet, but that may just be bad google-fu.

Comment: As soon as I post a question... I think I found a good summary of answers at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers.  Evaluating if they will work for us running on Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but still valid, so here is what I ended up using.

On [9.6 and above](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-admin.html), to set the values either of the following will work:

- `select set_config('app.userid', '3', true)`
- `SET LOCAL "app.userid" = 3;` (or `'3'`)

##### To read the value out (Postgres > 9.6)

For any remotely modern postgres, you can read the value and return `null` if it is not set. Thanks @motcke for the update in the comments.

```sql
-- pass `true` to return null if missing (see original answer)
userid := current_setting('app.user_id', true)
```

##### Original answer, for (Postgres <= 9.5)

I ended up wrapping the lookup for the userid or other field in a function, to handle the type conversion(s) and the fact that it might not be set:

For versions <= `9.5` (as the question was concerned):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_get_userid() RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE userid integer;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        userid := current_setting('app.userid');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN userid := NULL;
    END;
    return userid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: for getting the setting value, no need for the exception. you can use `current_setting('app.userid', true)` which return null if missing

Comment: True, on 9.6+ that is definitely correct.  I wrote the question for 9.1 it seems, but part of my answer (6 years later) mentions 9.6.  Very confusing.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks for catching that.